# Terraform Remote Exec Host IP from EC2 resource built

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

Looooong time lurker and first time poster here o/

I am currently trying to build an AWS EC2 instance with an EBS block device attached, which then needs MongoDB installed.

So I have gone the route of building the EC2 instance and attaching the EBS volume, but the remote-exec I need to run on the instance needs a host IP to connect to, to run the MongoDB install commands.

It just keeps timing out on the SSH, no matter what I try. Now I am probably just missing a step or going about this the wrong way, but hopefully you can help.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. :D

Below is the code sample I have slapped together:

```
    provider "aws" {
  region     = "eu-west-1"
  access_key = "xxxxxxx"
  secret_key = "xxxxxxxx"
}

resource "tls_private_key" "mongo" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "generated_key" {
  key_name   = "MongoKey"
  public_key = "${tls_private_key.mongo.public_key_openssh}"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["099720109477"]

  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }


}


resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami                         = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
    instance_type               = "t2.micro"
    key_name                    = "MongoKey"
    monitoring                  = true
    associate_public_ip_address = true


  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 40
  }

  ebs_block_device {
    volume_size = 100
    device_name = "xvda"    
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "MongoDB"
  }


    provisioner "remote-exec" {
            connection {
                type      = "ssh"
                user      = "ubuntu"
                host      = "MongoDB"
              }

      inline = [
        "sudo apt-get install gnupg",
        "wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -",
        "echo deb [ arch=amd64,arm64,s390x ] http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-enterprise/4.2 multiverse | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list",
        "sudo apt-get update",
        "sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise",
        "sudo service mongod start",
        "sudo service mongod status"
      ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your connection section as below

```
connection {
            type        = "ssh"
            user        = "ubuntu"
            host        = "${aws_instance.web.private_ip}"
            private_key = "${tls_private_key.mongo.private_key_pem}"

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to face connection issues/difficulties with your `remote-exec` approach, I would recommend considering the `user-data` parameter as a replacement.
the `user-data` script will run during the initialization of your instance so you do not have to open any ssh sessions to provision your resource.

You can accomplish this by updating your `aws_instance` resource to something like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami                         = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
    instance_type               = "t2.micro"
    key_name                    = "MongoKey"
    monitoring                  = true
    associate_public_ip_address = true


  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 40
  }

  ebs_block_device {
    volume_size = 100
    device_name = "xvda"    
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "MongoDB"
  }

    user_data = << EOF
        #! /bin/bash
        sudo apt-get install gnupg,
        wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -,
        echo deb [ arch=amd64,arm64,s390x ] http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-enterprise/4.2 multiverse | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list,
        sudo apt-get update,
        sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise,
        sudo service mongod start,
        sudo service mongod status
    EOF
  }
```

Hope this helps.

[more userdata examples](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Terraform/Terraform-terraform-userdata.php)